# Overriding an object in Alloy

Tags: alloy

I've been trying to make my project a little bit more dynamic, so I've decided to write an add function, I got inspired from this example they have on the Alloy website :

```
pred add [b, b': Book, n: Name, t: Target] {
  b'.addr = b.addr + n->t 
}
```

But what I want to do is override the two objects "b" and "b' " (as in I want to add to the same object) but i can't seem to find a way how to do it.

If anyone has an idea I'll be thankful

Answer (score 0):

You're not missing anything.  The reason you cannot find a way to "add to the same object" is that you can't.  Alloy doesn't have mutation; you cannot change any object in a model.

Applications that involve mutation are often modeled just as you model `add` in your example:  with two parameters showing the pre-state and the post-state.  In such a model, any two `Book` objects *b1*, *b2* will show different states of the same mutable `Book` object in the application domain if and only if there is some *n*, *t* such that add[b1, b2, n, t] holds.

Comment: I understood that but I was still hoping to find a way !! thnx alot for ur answer !!